# the collision in Kuramoto model is not occur for the identical case.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Kuramoto model is following
$$\dot{\theta_i}=\omega_i+K/N\sum_{j=1}^N \sin(\theta_j-\theta_i),t>0,i=1,2,\dots,N.$$

where $\theta_i=\theta_i(t)\in \mathbb{R}$, $w_i=\dot{\theta}(0)$(intrinsic frequeny) K is coupling strength constant, N is the Number of oscillators.

and the definition of collision is following
for $i\neq j$, we say the oscillators $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$ collide at time $t_*>0$ if
$$\theta_i(t_*)=\theta_j(t_*)+2k\pi$$ for soem integer $k$.

In the paper, for the identical case( $\omega_i=\omega,\ \  \forall i$
),no collision occur because of the nature of the first order autonomous ode. (one can prove it the uniqueness argument.)

I don't know how to prove why no collsion occur in identical case.

Please give me a help if you have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of uniform angular base velocities, you get for angle differences
\begin{align}
\dot \theta_i &=\omega+K/N\sum_{m=1}^N \sin(\theta_m-\theta_i)\\
\dot \theta_i -\dot \theta_i 
&=K/N\sum_{m=1}^N [\sin(\theta_m-\theta_i)-\sin(\theta_m-\theta_j)]\\
&=2K/N\sum_{m=1}^N \cos(\theta_m-\tfrac12(\theta_i+\theta_j))\sin(\tfrac12(\theta_j-\theta_i))
\end{align}
So if a collision occurs at some point, the derivative of the difference will be zero. Thus there is a solution with constant difference. By uniqueness this is also the only variant where a collision occurs.

Comment: Assume the collision is occur at $t_*$, I understand that $\dot{\theta_i}(t_*)-\dot{\theta_j}(t_*)=0$, but I can't understand why this imply there exist a solution with constant difference.

Comment: You can set $θ_j=θ_i$, eliminate the $j$ equation and solve the system. That the difference equation is identically satisfied tells you that this gives a solution of the original system. Uniqueness tells now that no other solution can enter, leave or cross the hyperplane $θ_j=θ_i$. Thus it is the other way around, the solution exists and thus forces any hypothetical collision solution to already be a constant-difference solution.

Comment: jejus I understand what you mean thank you